# Unable to locate stylesheet classes in PHP wordpress website

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to modify a WordPress website. I need to make some changes in the style. But when I logged into the WordPress dashboard, I was unable to find the style classes whose properties needs to be changed. I found those classes when I did "Inspect Element" from a web browser.

Luckily I found out a style.css file & custom.css file in the WordPress dashboard. This is the class I am looking for `caroufredsel_wrapper`. this class is assigned to a div element.

I searched for it in styles.css file, but it didn't contain it. custom.css file was empty. I wrote the needed changes to the class in that file, but nothing changed.
I am new to Wordpress. Can anyone give me some quick tips to resolve the style issues or how can I change them?

Comment: What theme are you currently using?

Comment: Blanco-responsive-wordpress-wooecommerce-theme from theme forest @Dre

Comment: As it's a premium theme I can't look at it to see how it works under the hood, but it appears that the custom.css file is where you put your changes. First you need to check if custom.css is *actually* being loaded; does it show up under the resources in the web inspector? A link to the site would be helpful.

Comment: I have added the link. @Dre

Comment: custom.css is an empty file when I view it from the dashboard. @Dre

Comment: where the class is in your html/source code?

Comment: it doesn't matter what changes do you need for the code, one of the most important rules is to create a child theme: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes because if you will not, your code changes will be gone after updating the theme for example. 

some themes comes already with a child theme for helping you out with this, check it before...if there isn't, create it by following the link above step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@amit was on the right track: the classes are being added inline, which means it's probably being added via JS. The likely culprit is `jquery.carouFredSel.min.js`. While you could override the JS yourself, or write your own script to add styles this would probably give you headaches later on if you update your theme. Doing some digging I find that `jquery.carouFredSel.min.js` is being loaded by the [carouFredSel WordPress Plugin;](http://dev7studios.com/products/caroufredsel-wordpress-plugin) a quick glance at the [plugin support page](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel) shows that there are user settings and probably some kind of control panel in the dashboard that you can use. I'd recommend playing with that first before you commit to overriding actual JS files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about inline css which is added by jquery script.

```
element.style {
bottom: auto;
display: block;
float: none;
height: 181px;
left: auto;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
right: auto;
text-align: left;
top: auto;
width: 328px;
z-index: auto;
```

}

Comment: Yes. How can I change it from the wordpress dashboard. I ain't got no FTP credentials. @amit

Comment: Try to find the js file or simply Write own script that runs after pageload.